# Coronasdk: How to check that if the object is in collision state or not?

Tags: collision-detection, coronasdk

Since I still do not buy corona, I still cannot use their forum.
Hope someone here may have the answer for me.

I got the problem about collision.
Since collision Api's event phase has only "began" and "ended"
I set the object's move flag = false when collision is in "began" state
and set flag = true when collision is in "ended" state.

However, during collision event, when the collision' opponent was suddenly disappeared(after enter to "began" state),
The object will stay in "began" state. Even though, there is nothing collide to the object,
the state is still in "began". I wonder why the state is not change to "ended"

I have checked on object api but there is no property such as "isCollision"...

I do not know what is going on with the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 3 days has passed and no one replied....
I found some solution about this  but may be not a best solution.
Anyway, hope this will be useful for another people.

My solution is making the old traditional collision check(without physic) such as sphere collision or box collision.